# Entity Framework Code First ASP.Net and DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, dbcontext

Long time lurker of the forums, I have a question based on the MVC Music Store Tutorial (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4) I am following.

The tutorial uses EF Code First to set up a CE database. However there are three models Album, Genre and Artist as class files. Now 1 Album can have many Artists however the code only mentions the Genre and Artist:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this code mention say:

```
public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
```

Thank for reading. I hope I am not being too stupid.

Comment: You only need to expose a `DbSet` if you would like to query it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because Album has Artist in it so we can access artist by album:

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int      AlbumId     { get; set;
}
        public int      GenreId     { get; set; }
        public int      ArtistId    { get; set; }
        public string   Title       { get; set; }
        public decimal  Price       { get; set; }
        public string   AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
        public Genre    Genre       { get; set; }
        public Artist   Artist      { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure if that was the case I will mark correct once stackoverflow lets me!